# Looping through multiple moveToElement in selenium/webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click through all of these nested links inside a mouse over web element. The first iteration works, but it stops after that. I've tried adding `Thread.Sleep(xxxx);` but that doesn't work either. Here's my method:

```
public static bool TestFindAssets()
    {
        bool result = false;
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        var findAssetsClick = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/header/nav/ul/li[3]/a"));
        var home = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Home"));
        try
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
            {
                action.MoveToElement(findAssetsClick).Perform(); //Find Assets Link
                action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath"))).Perform(); //By Type Link
                action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("otherPath"+i))).Click().Build().Perform(); //list of links

            }

             result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error occurred: ", ex);
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Again, this works for one iteration. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what you get? `StaleElement` exception?

Comment: This is the tricky part: Since I'm running as a Unit Test, the `Assert.IsTrue(LinksWork);` fails. All I know from the behavior is that the automation clicks the first link and does not start the process over. @Saifur

Comment: You should collect stacktrace anyway. The common issue in such case is `DOM` refreshes when you click on a link and after coming back to the **previous** elements are not there anymore and throws `StaleElement` exception.

Comment: @Saifur yes, `A first chance exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException' occurred in WebDriver.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard coded index number you should find the target elements with `FindElements` then loop though and click back and forth. 
Second think, you need to use proper wait time to make sure the elements are loaded properly.
Third, Need to find the element on the fly cannot simply iterate through the collection and click back and forth. It will refresh the `DOM` and throw `StaleElement` reference exception.

Here is a sample test which is doing the same thing you are trying to do

```
public void ClickThroughLinks()
{
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.cnn.com/");
    //Maximize the window so that the list can be gathered successfully.
    Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    //find the list
    By xPath = By.XPath("//h2[.='The Latest']/../li//a");
    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> linkCollection = Driver.FindElements(xPath);

    for (int i = 0; i < linkCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        //wait for the elements to be exist
        new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(xPath));

        //Click on the elements by index
        Driver.FindElements(xPath)[i].Click();
        Driver.Navigate().Back();
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect after the first link is navigated to, when you navigate back for the second link to execute, it will throw a `StaleElementReferenceException` as the page has been revisited again and the DOM, in fact, has refreshed. Have you run this code and checked ? Thanks.. :)

Comment: @Subh You may have noticed every time I come to the page then find the collection of elements and then click on `i`th element. There is no reason for `StaleElementReference` exception would happen because of `DOM` refresh. What makes you think like that though and, yes, I tested this!

Comment: The first problem I'm having is that although I'm running .NET version 4.5, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` is not being found in `System.Collections.Generic;` Also, none of the other data structures I've tried will allow me to impicitly set the collection to type `Driver.FindElement(xPath);` @Saifur

Comment: You can simply use `var` and that's `FindElements` not `FindElement` I guess is a typo.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo on my part. In what context can I replace the Collection with `var`? @Saifur

Comment: Yes like `var linkCollection = Driver.FindElements(xPath);`

Comment: And `IReadOnlyCollection<T> Interface` is present in `.NET 4.5` see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's member of `System.Collections.Generic` namespace .You have to import `using System.Collections.Generic;` reference

Comment: Yes, this is the frustrating part. The import is present, but Visual Studio continues to say that `The type or namespace 'IReadOnlyCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I replaced the collection with `var` and the test passed - but it clearly did not click through all of the links. @Saifur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68885/discussion-between-saifur-and-justin-ertley).

Comment: @Saifur: Oh! Yes yes., my bad.. It had skipped my vision.. Thanks for clearing that up.. :)