# How to handle StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I have a scenario where I am attempting to loop through  a number of elements on a bar chart, until I find the "rect" tag name. When I click on the "rect" tag name, the individual bar is selected from the chart, and I am redirect to another page. Please see below for an image of the bar chart I am working with:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4LNm.jpg

For reference, the bar chart  I am working with is the top right-hand side. The test I want to execute is to click on the first bar in the chart; doing so, will redirect me to an appropriate page. In order to do this I have written the following code in Selenium Webdriver using Eclipse (Java):

```
WebElement deliveredChartDailyFocus = driver.findElement(By.id("delivered-chart-daily"));
deliveredChartDailyFocus.click();

List<WebElement> children = deliveredChartDailyFocus.findElements(By.tagName("rect"));
Iterator<WebElement> iter = children.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
WebElement we = iter.next();

if(we.isDisplayed()){
we.click();
}
```

Everything appears to work well in that the above code hits the “rect” element and redirects me to the appropriate page. However, when I hit the page I then get an error as the code is still looking for the “rect” value which isn’t on the new page.

You’ll notice that there is a “break” line missing from the above…..this is because, upon debugging the code I found that when iterating through the loop, the click event does not kick in until the 3rd iteration, I’m assuming because the “rect” element is not visible? Therefore, if I put in a “break” statement it exits out of the loop after the first iteration, and therefore I never get to the part where I carry out the “click” event to navigate to the new page.

Essentially, what I’m after is a way of being able to loop as many times as necessary until the appropriate “rect” element can be located. Upon clicking on that, I am redirected to the new page….only at that point do I want the loop to exit, so that the “NoSuchElementException error is not displayed.

If any more details are required please let me know, would really appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you're on the new page all those `rect` elements are gone. Exercising any references to those `rect` elements will trigger this `StaleElementReferenceException`.

So don't reference those elements after the click. Iterate to the first displayed `rect` element then stop iterating.

```
WebElement deliveredChartDailyFocus = driver.findElement(By.id("delivered-chart-daily"));
deliveredChartDailyFocus.click();

// Get a list of all the <rect> elements under the #delivered-chart-daily element
List<WebElement> children = deliveredChartDailyFocus.findElements(By.tagName("rect"));

WebElement elementToClick = null; // variable for the element we want to click on
for (WebElement we : children)    // loop through all our <rect> elements
{
    if (we.isDisplayed())
    {
        elementToClick = we;      // save the <rect> element to our variable
        break;                    // stop iterating
    }
}

if (elementToClick != null)       // check we have a visible <rect> element
{
    elementToClick.click();
}
else
{
    // Handle case if no displayed rect elements were found
}
```

Comment: John, that's absolutely brilliant, thank you. I'm still getting to grips with the core java programming skills as I'm learning more and more about selenium. Stepping through the code in debug mode, that you have provided, has really helped me understand this for future reference

Comment: @John_O As I circled back and read this solution I must admit this is absolutely brilliant implementation

Answer (score 1):

Andy, the issue here is `DOM` refresh. You can not simply get the collection of `IWebElements` and iterate through and click back and forth. You **can** find the count of the elements and every time you come to the page find the element you want to click dynamically. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952450/looping-through-multiple-movetoelement-in-selenium-webdriver-c-sharp/27953326#27953326) for implementation

```
public void ClickThroughLinks()
{

    _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.cnn.com/");
    //Maximize the window so that the list can be gathered successfully.
    _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    //find the list
    By xPath = By.XPath("//h2[.='The Latest']/../li//a");
    var linkCollection = _driver.FindElements(xPath);

    for (int i = 0; i < linkCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        //wait for the elements to be exist
        new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(xPath));

        //Click on the elements by index
        if (i<=3)
        {
            _driver.FindElements(xPath)[i].Click();

        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        _driver.Navigate().Back();
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Saifur, thanks for the comments. Yes, I'm aware that the issue is the DOM refresh as the "rect" element is no longer on the page that I am redirected to. Does this implementation step out of the loop so that when I arrive at the new page, the "rect" element is no longer being searched for?

Comment: No it does not. But, it finds the element on the fly

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I will go through the implementation and see if it meets the requirements I need. What I'm after is the ability exit out of the loop once I arrive at the new page so that it no longer searches for the "rect" element on the DOM, thus causing the error I am getting

Comment: if you want to break the loop after meeting your criteria you can simply use a if condition and if that meets the criteria just simply use `break`

Comment: The problem I have with that is it isn't until the loop iterates through 3 times that the click on the "rect" takes place. Therefore, by putting a "break" statement in, it is exiting out of the loop on the first iteration4

Comment: then add another if condition to match the `i` with 3 and then break

Comment: When you say to add another "if" condition, can you advise at which point I should be doing this in my code?