# How to use Selenium function back() and I loss my variable in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Python.

I met a BIG problem in Python!!

I visit a website and put about 200 options from a dropdownlist in a array.

I want to click every options in the array and click javascript button to submit.

Take something I want from that page and back to previous page click another option.

Do those actions about 200 times in a for loop.

Here is the code:

```
for option in arrName:
    if count > 0:
        option.click()
        string = u'Something'
        link2 = browser.find_element_by_link_text(string.encode('utf8'))
        link2.click()
        //"do something I want"
        browser.back()
    count = count +1
```

In this code, I don't want to use first option.

PROBLEM comes,after the program click the second option, click the link2, and `browser.back()`, it answer me:

```
` StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element 
is not attached to the page document
```

that means the options in array disappear?

How should I use the options in the array when the `browser.back()` in for loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is happening because of `DOM` refresh. You cannot simply iterate over an array and click back and forth. Best option is to find the element in runtime and then click. Avoid `option.click()` instead, find the next element with `find_element`. If you are not sure how to accomplish that then please provide the `html`

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. If I can't accomplish it , please let me ask again and I will provide the html page !!

Comment: @趙偉丞 [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193303/how-to-handle-staleelementreferenceexception/28193888#28193888) is an implementation in `Java`. Hope not too hard to understand.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!  It workssssssssss. I count the length about selection to run for loop,  and find element every times to click.